# Selenium WebDriver for AWS Device Farm error when sending period "." keystroke to element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara, aws-device-farm

I'm moving test execution of RSpec/Capybara tests to AWS Device Farm. I'm having an issue when sending an individual period (".") to a field. Here is my binding.pry debug session:

```
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Drivers>)> find('input[id^="filter"]').set('.')
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: You are trying to work with something that isn't a file.
from /Users/pfong/.rbenv/versions/3.0.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:422:in `upload'
```

It works fine if I send multiple characters. However in this case I'm looking to send one key at a time slowly in another helper method.

I'm not sure why it thinks I'm sending a file when I'm clearly trying to hit keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug/feature in selenium-webdriver - when keys are sent to an element the following code is called

```
def send_keys_to_element(element, keys)
      # TODO: rework file detectors before Selenium 4.0
      if @file_detector
        local_files = keys.first&.split("\n")&.map { |key| @file_detector.call(Array(key)) }&.compact
        if local_files.any?
          keys = local_files.map { |local_file| upload(local_file) }
          keys = Array(keys.join("\n"))
        end
      end
      ...
    end
```

Selenium 4 changed to have a default file detector on the remote driver defined as

```
->((filename, *)) { File.exist?(filename) && filename.to_s }
```

so that is triggering because '.' does exist (the current directory).  A workaround would be to reset the driver file_detector to nil after it's created.

```
current_session.driver.browser.file_detector = nil
```

Comment: As usual Thomas, you've rescued me out of a bind. I ended up setting `Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.file_detector = nil` in my helper method and my input is now working.

Is it worthwhile to try to report this up to SeleniumHQ?

Comment: Probably, this is an unforeseen side-effect of the change in Selenium 4. I’m considering having Capybara reset it to nil after driver creation since Capybara sets it’s own when interacting with file input elements